# how is this slider done it looks to be js but its altering the url with each slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

I just came across this site, http://www.so-design.co.uk/#/brand/1 , if you use the slider it changes the image just like any normal image slider but it also changes the url to /brand/1, /brand/2 ect which i suppose means that all the slides and their content are crawled by search engines as individual pages

any ideas how they are doing this ?
cheers

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page and less complicated: `window.location.hash`

Comment: its Flash, right-click it to see that

Comment: @micha: In regards to the question. the OP seems to be under the impression this is a javascript control. However, it is clear that Adobe Flash has been used. Plus, your possible duplicate shout does not seem correct to me

Comment: @musefan ohh I see you're right but as you can see in this file: http://www.so-design.co.uk/js/swfaddress.js JavaScript `window.location.hash` has been used for changing url. Because I don't except that you read all that I give you the hint that the var `_t` is `window` and  `_l` is `window.location`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to do when you want to try and work out how a website has been developed is to view the source code.

The quickest way to do this is to right-click the page and look for "View page source" or something similar (depending on your browser)

Of course, in this instance, when you right-click it should become obvious that the website uses [Adobe Flash](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash.html). Therefore, this is not a typical JavaScript slider as you first seemed to assume.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [manipulating the browser's history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) as well as the [`history property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history). Also, [reading the hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Properties) using`window.location.hash`